# MySQL: Atomically inserting into a table and into a related table simultaniously

Tags: mysql, sql, atomic

I have two tables, a `TaskLists` table with an automatically generated primary key and a `Tasks` table. A `TaskList` can have multiple `Tasks`.

How would I now insert a `TaskLists` row and at the same time atomically insert none to multiple rows into the `Tasks` table which reference the just inserted object.

Comment: You could use triggers

Comment: You need to use a transaction, so you can roll it back or commit it at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to general relativity, nothing in this universe happens at the "same time", so you can't. :)

However, you can start a transaction, insert a row into `TaskList`, insert corresponding rows into `Task` and then commit the transaction. That would certainly be "atomic" in a sense that you couldn't (permanently) write partial data in the database.

If `TaskList`'s ID is auto-incremented, you can get it via [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and then use it for `Task`'s FK.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `triggers` that happends `AFTER INSERT`

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON TaskList FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- Insert the rows to tasks now

   INSERT INTO tasks (TaskID) VALUES (NEW.TaskId);

   -- You can run several insert statements here
END;
```

If you want to make use of the values from `TaskList`, use the `NEW.columname`

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php

Comment: A trigger is not atomic per se if it's not executed inside a transaction, if one query fails for whatever reason the queries before the faulting one will remain executed no matter what.